# Custom distance metric for OpenCV matcher

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on stitching several images taken from a drone using the SIFT and BFMatcher on OpenCV. In addition to the descriptors produced by SIFT I also have an approximate (quite good actually) mapping of pixels to ground coordinates and was hoping of using this information to improve the qualities of the matches.

My first approach was to first run BFMatcher normally and then filter the matches based on the physical distance between the key points to remove potentially bad/unphysical matches. However, I thought that using a custom metric that penalizes physically distant matches during the actual matching algorithm would be a nice addition.

Is it possible to define a custom distance function in Python and pass it to BFMatcher? As far as I can tell you can only use those defined under [NormTypes](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gad12cefbcb5291cf958a85b4b67b6149f)

Comment: What do you mean by physical distance of the keypoints? Matcher is used to get the correspondences between the two sets, but it can't take intra-set-evaluations into account. One approach which might work for you is to compute a homography from matches, to verify the geometric probabilities/relationships (and correct matches then are the inliers of homography estimation). To my knowledge there is no combined matching + homography estimation, but you could try to implement it yourself. You could also implement your own BF matcher, which is quite simple.

Comment: By physical distances I meant ground distances. Since I can find approximate ground coordinates for each pixel I can calculate also distances on the ground between them. My idea would have been to augment the descriptor of a point with its ground coordinates and then use a custom distance function that takes this into consideration. I considered the homography idea but didn't pursue it further but may still try it. I will try to go with my own implementation of the BFMatcher by looking at the OpenCV source if no other solutions come in.

Comment: If I understand it right, you have the real ground points A where you know their real positions. And you have the image-to-ground-points B. Now in the matching between A and B you want to check whether for two points in A, A1 and A2, where their distance isn known, the matched points B1' and B2' have similar distance? In the standard matching process, for each point in B the best correspondences in A are searched, but a point in B is not compared to other points in B, so BFMatcher isn probably no the right interface for you. Instead you can implement the matching without using that interface.

Comment: I have more than that. For both A and B images I have a function that produces a good approximation that takes you from pixel coordinates to ground coordinates (think latitude and longitude). Having that, if you give me a pixel from A and a pixel from B I can tell you (approximately) how far they are in meters on the ground. If the matching algorithm tells me that there is match between points A' and B' that I can estimate are a 100m away on the ground I know then that this is a false match and can filter it out (my current approach).

Comment: ok, then it makes sense and you could implement your own BFMatcher with opencv matcher interface or you can implement it without that interface, both possible.